# How do I package config data for my web application that can be updated?

Tags: java, web-applications, classpath

I have a web service that provides clients with configuration data. It receives a request containing a version (ex: "v1") of that configuration data and needs to retrieve the data associated with that version. **New versions of configuration data can be added while the web service is running.**

The directory structure of the configuration data is:

```
config
    v1
        ...config files...
    v2
        ...config files...
    v3
        ...config files...
```

I know that web application best practices state I should not use java.io.File and should instead use ClassLoader.getResource(), so how do I go about doing that? I can't compile my config data into a JAR because it can be updated while the service is running, so do I place the data on the filesystem and add that directory to my classpath?

Comment: If your problem is solved (and not by my answer) you should definitely answer your own question, and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We didn't find any way to do this with Weblogic, so we updated the application to read the data from the filesystem instead of the classpath.